# Object ContextShift is not a member of package cats.effect

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I'm trying to implement basic cats app, however I cannot find any solution how to overcome problem with lack of ContextShift inside cats.effect._. I've checked manually all of External Libraries and truly, there is no ContextShift.

Here's my dependencies in build.sbt:

```
val CatsVersion = "2.6.1"
val CatsEffectVersion = "3.4.8"
...

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-ember-server" % Http4sVersion,
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-ember-client" % Http4sVersion,
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-circe" % Http4sVersion,
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-dsl" % Http4sVersion,
      "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % CatsVersion,
      "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % CatsEffectVersion,
      "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect-kernel" % CatsEffectVersion,
      "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % CirceVersion,
      "org.tpolecat" %% "doobie-core" % DoobieVersion,
      "org.tpolecat" %% "doobie-postgres" % DoobieVersion,
      "org.tpolecat" %% "doobie-hikari" % DoobieVersion,
      "org.tpolecat" %% "doobie-scalatest" % DoobieVersion % Test,
      "org.scalameta" %% "munit" % MunitVersion % Test,
      "org.typelevel" %% "munit-cats-effect-3" % MunitCatsEffectVersion % Test,
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % LogbackVersion % Runtime,
      "org.scalameta" %% "svm-subs" % "20.2.0"
    )
```

Change to different cats and cats.effect versions.

Comment: `ContextShift` not longer exists on **CE3**, if you are following some tutorial that is outdated you may either use the outdated versions or follow a different tutorial. You may also ask what would be the best way to replace some specific usage of `ContextShift`

Comment: https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/thread-model provides a rough comparison between CE2 and CE3 and goes over some of why `ContextShift` is suboptimal.